# Xcode 4 and debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ibaction

I've setup a break point (Left click in gutter) in some methods. I've also wired the control to the method (in IB). However when I press CMD + R, it ignores my breakpoints. How do I make Xcode stop at breakpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on Activate/Deactivate Breakpoints to deactivate breakpoints and activate it again. Then Build and Debug. If it still doesn't work then remove Breakpoints and add breakpoint again (this is what worked for me when gdb doesn't hit the breakpoint)

Comment: Its Build and Run in XCode4. I thought it was XCode3 so I said build and debug

Comment: Im on Xcode 4.2 to be exact and it looks like debug has been removed and you need to use Intruments